# Solving the Poisson-Schrodinger equations numerically

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, software

I need to find the solution to the Poisson- Schrodinger equation in the newtonian approximation, which are basically coupled differential equations given by:
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 V=8\pi G M^{2}\psi^{2}\\
\frac{1}{2M}\nabla^2 \psi+MV\psi=E\psi
\end{equation}
we are taking the case of stationary rotations, therefore, $\psi$ only depends on (r, $\theta$), we expand it using the Legendre polynomials given by;
\begin{equation*}
\psi(r,\theta) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\sum_{l=m}^{\infty}R_{l}(r)P_{l}^{m}(\theta)
\end{equation*}
and the potential is assumed to be;
\begin{equation}
V(r, \theta)= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} V_{l}(r)P_{l}(\theta)
\end{equation}
inserting these into the above coupled equations gives a system of differential equations which I was able to reduce using the following rescaling parameters;
$\hat{r} =\hat{N} M r
$,  $
V(r,\theta) =\hat{N}\hat{V}(\hat{r},\theta)$,  $
R(r) =\hat{N}^2(2G)^{-1/2} \hat{R}(\hat{r})$,  $
E  = M \hat{N}^2 \hat{E}^2$,  $
\hat{N} =G \hat{M}^2 N \frac{(2l+1)(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}$
using these rescaling parameters and the orthogonality of the legendre polynomials, I was able to reduce the differential equation for the ground state to the equations given by;
\begin{align}
\hat{V}_{0}''+ \frac{2}{\hat{r}}\hat{V}_{0}' &=\hat{R}_{0}^{2}\nonumber\\
\frac{1}{2}\left[ \hat{R}_{0}'' + \frac{2}{\hat{r}}\hat{R}_{0}'\right]+\hat{R}_{0}\hat{E}_{0}&=\hat{V}_{0}\hat{R}_{0}+\frac{\alpha}{\hat{r}}\hat{R}_{0}
\end{align}
I'm having trouble solving this equation computationally. I have tried it on mathematica by entering the exact differential equations into the NDSolve but it always keeps telling me initial conditions are not enough to solve these equations numerically. Any help with regards to how I'm supposed to go about solving this using mathematica or Python would be extremely useful.

Comment: Can you upload your Mathematica code?

Comment: Keep in mind it would be more on topic to ask for a numerical method to solve these than for us do address issues with using Mathematica, since there is an SE for that.

Comment: What is $\alpha$? If it is a constant, it seems that the second equation does not depend on the first, which seems unlikely.

Comment: $\alpha$ is  the fine structure constant. It's basically a perturbation term added to the potential.

Comment: I apologise, there was an error in the last term. Instead of $\hat{E}_0$, it is supposed to be $\hat{V}_0$.

Comment: Since we also don't have your boundary conditions, we'll have as much trouble to help you as mathematica... More seriously, you need to impose the correct behavior of your functions at the origin and infinity, which is what mathematica is missing. How to do that in practice (or what other method to use) is not for this SE indeed.